# Creating dir and loading file from relative path

Tags: c, gtk

I am using C and gtk, I need to create a dir at /home/demo/.config and load a file from this dir uisng a relative path. I am writing in C and gtk 2.0.

I use `g_build_filename` for the moment, but this will only work if the dir exists, it won't create a new one.

Thanks for all the help!

Edit:

Managed to create the needed dir. Now I need to check if the file exists.

like this:

```
if(!file_exists)
{
//file doesn't exist
}
else if(file_exists)
{
//file_exists
}
```

Comment: 'if(!file_exists)
{
//file doesn't exist }else if(file_exists)
{
//file_exists
}'. Better change that to if(!file_exists)
{
//file doesn't exist
}
else
{
//file_exists
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [`g_mkdir_with_parents()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-mkdir-with-parents) to create the directory, before trying to access the file. It will create all needed directories. You don't need to check for the file to exist, just open it. The open will fail if the file doesn't exist, and of course you need to handle that sensibly. All I/O can fail.

Of course, you probably also shouldn't hardcode the `/home/demo/.config` part but rather read out the current user name (or use some API, probably [`g_get_user_config_dir()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-user-config-dir) for this).